# Preventing JavaScript code from running by removing from the page source at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somebody entered XSS code in my friend's site. It inserts `<script>alert(0)</script>` in the page source. You can see it [here](http://technoflexusdatastreamapi.appspot.com/listData).

Is there a way to remove this from the page at runtime, to prevent it from being executed?

He has a presentation on it tomorrow and he has no access to database to remove it.

Comment: You could use the same xss vulnerability to remove it that the other person used to add it,

Comment: Does he have access to the serverside code?

Comment: Why is there no `<body>` element?

Comment: Why not fix the code to properly escape output? If it's his site, clearly he should be able to update it.

Comment: He is the coder , but admin login and mysql database password wasn't set by him , and the guy who set it isn't accessible.

Comment: the username and password for the db is probably in some plain text file somewhere that lets the page access the data.

Comment: If you have access to edit the web pages and this (http://technoflexusdatastreamapi.appspot.com/landingpage) is the page you want to keep the alert from popping up on you can do what @Alen Moran says below before the .load and re-enable alert after the load is complete.

Answer (score 2):

As a really quick fix. If he has access to the javascript he could do a simple trick like below.

```
   alert = function() {}
```

This will stop all alerts from firing.

Comment: You definitely can't put it in `$(function () { });` because that'll be too later to overwrite `alert`. I'd go back to your original and not include your change, and make sure it's run as soon as possible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `alert` on http://technoflexusdatastreamapi.appspot.com/landingpage before loading the data:

```
$('.viewDataLink').click(function ()
{
    $("#scriptShow").hide();
    $("#showData").show();
    $("#progressAnimation").show();
    var tmpAlert = alert;
    window.alert = function () { };
    $("#showData").load("/listData", function (response, status, xhr)
    {
        if (status == "success")
        {
            $("#progressAnimation").hide();
            window.alert = tmpAlert;
        }
    });
});
```